# external Monitor via Thinkpad Dock with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, external-monitor

I am trying to configure my new Thinkpad with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Desktop) and connecting it via Docking-Station (USB-C connector) to an external monitor (see details below). I tried different suggestions (like installing additional DisplayLink drivers) but did not suceed.

I then tried the most recent desktop version (23.04) and the external monitor worked out-of-the-box (but not usb-mouse and network via docking-station).

Then I tried Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Desktop and everything worked (monitor, mouse, network).

So currently I would have to install 20.04 as my Desktop and stick to it at least until the next LTS is released as I do emphasize stability in my setup :)

Is there some trick to get 22.04 working after all?

thx

Details:

```
Thinkpad T14s Gen3 (AMD cpu) 
Docking-Station: Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock (Type: 40AC, Model No: DBB9003L1) 
Monitor: Dell U2715H connected via Display Port cable
```

Comment: Update: Today i received a new kernel (version 5.15.0-83-generic) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now again the external display is no longer working :(